# How to access function return value in Greasemonkey on FF4

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, firefox4

Firefox 4 implemented a new security wrapper called [XrayWrapper](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPConnect_wrappers) and the docs that I have been able to find say, for functions, that "the default is for functions to be created as safe by default"

```
var MyObj = {};
MyObj.Util = {
    myFunc : function() {
        content = '<table class="tupleList"><tr><td>192.168.1.1</td></tr></table>';
        return content;
    }
};

content = MyObj.Util.myFunc();
console.log(content);
```

When in Greasemonkey's world, the above logs to Firebug

> ok/ok: [object XrayWrapper [object Window]]

My question is how to get at that string that I made in the function of the MyObj object. I've tried printing the wrappedJSObject property of the wrapped content, but that just returns

> ok/ok: [object Window]

Any help would be appreciated. Also, are there MDN documentation links that explain this stuff better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was you trying to set [`window.content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.content) which is a window property that you cannot change, then you returned `window.content`. Properly scoping the `content` variable fixes your problem for this reason; also renaming the variable will fix the issue.

If you're interested in why the example code works differently in a web page, then it does in a GM script, that is because `window` for a user script [is a wrapped object](http://wiki.greasespot.net/XPCNativeWrapper).

Comment: sorry Brock, but you are Wrong. Give it a try for yourself..: https://gist.github.com/897463

Comment: Hmm. Well I guess Eric is technically right, although changing the scope made it work too as he and Brock suggested. I didn't think that I would be referencing the content property of the window object by just assigning stuff to "content". I would have expected "window.content" to assign stuff to window.content.

Comment: No, Eric is more wrong than right -- As shown by the fact that the OP's code works fine in the console.  It only fails from within the GM sandbox due to scope confusion vis-à-vis the wrapping.

Comment: I'm a GM contributor so I probably have a little more credibility than  someone that simply says I'm wrong in a comment and then deletes the comment after laboriously being shown to be wrong themself..

Comment: @Broc "No, Eric is more wrong than right -- As shown by the fact that the OP's code works fine in the console" it doesn't work fine in the console, the code is overwriting window.content..

Comment: Overwriting window.content is obviously not a problem (and it's not read-only) as the script worked fine in FF 3.6, and in the console, and in a quick and dirty test page.   Only when the wrapping changed did a problem arise. Overwriting window.content is a poor practice, but the sandbox differences in FF 4 broke this script.